# ReactJs does not re-render dom elements on select component

Tags: reactjs

I create a custom select component and when I update the options from a parent the render method does not re-render my options on the select element.

Below is my code:

The select component:

```html
render(){

return(
  <select type='select'

        multiple={this.props.isMultiSelect}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
        value={this.props.value}
        label={this.props.value}
        items={this.props.items}
        placeHolder={this.props.placeHolder}
        onChange={this.handleChange} >

  {() => {
    if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length >0) {
      this.props.items.map(this.renderSelectOption);
    }
  }}
           
</select>);
}

renderSelectOption(item){
  return (
    <option label={item.label} value={item.value}></option>
  );
}
```

Here is the parent component where the select component is setup with the items property with data coming from ajax request:

```html
Parent Component

<MySelect key={'templatesPickListKey'}
          ref={'templatesPicklist'}
          placeHolder={'Select Template...'}
          items={this.state.myItems}
          onChange={event => {this.setState({selectedTemplate: event.target.value});}}
          isMultiSelect={false}
  />
```

I also have a button which I am using just to initiate the ajax request and return data to my component. I am using a Promise implementation which when it comes back it changes my state. When I debug I see everything and when it goes into the select render method it does not seem to iterate thought the items.

Here is what I came up with for my select component. It works, but I am not sure about whether my usage of state and props is following best practice, any thoughts would be appreciated:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class MySelectComponent extends Component {

 static propTypes = {
  key: React.PropTypes.string,
  isMultiSelect: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  initialOptions: React.PropTypes.array,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func,
  disabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
  placeHolder: React.PropTypes.string,
  value: React.PropTypes.string,
  label: React.PropTypes.string
 }
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {}

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
 }
 renderOptions() {
  let options = [];
  if (this.props.placeHolder) {
   options.push(<option label={this.props.placeHolder} value=""></option>); 
  }
  if (this.state.options) {
   this.state.options.map(option => {
    options.push(<option label={option.label} value={option.value}></option>); 
   });
  } else if (this.props.initialOptions) {
   this.props.initialOptions.map(option => {
    options.push(<option label={option.label} value={option.value}></option>); 
   });
  }
  return options;
 }
 handleChange(event) {
  if (typeof this.props.onChange === "function") {
   this.props.onChange(event);
  }
 }
 render() {
  return(
    <select type='select'
      multiple={this.props.isMultiSelect}
      disabled={this.props.disabled}
      value={this.props.value}
      label={this.props.value}
      initialOptions={this.props.initialOptions}
      placeHolder={this.props.placeHolder}
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
      >
      {this.renderOptions()}     
    </select>
   );   
 }
}
```

And here is how I include it into a parent components:

```js
<MySelectComponent key={'templatesPickListKey'}
          ref={'templatesPicklist'}
          placeHolder={'Select Template...'}
          onChange={event => {this.setState({selectedTemplate: event.target.value});}}
          isMultiSelect={false}
            />
                            
                            
This method makes a remote call and returns teh value by setState(args..) on my SelectComponent.

myPromise.then(result => {
    let myOptions = [];
    for (var key in result) {
     myOptions.push({label: key, value: result[key]});
    }
    this.refs.templatesPicklist.setState({options: myOptions});
   })
   .catch(error => {
    console.error("error: " + error);
   });
```

Comment: I updated my post with what I came up with in the interim.

Comment: Your code has so many errors.. =/  but most importantly, you can't call `setState()` on a `ref`, which is just a DOM node..

Comment: I am having this problem too. And it's unfortunate the people who are trying to "answer" this question are picking on typos rather than the actual problem, which is that the select option values are not able to dynamically update.

Answer (score 0):

edit: I noticed in your example the function names don't line up. Your custom select render uses `this.handleChange` but your parent passes `onChange`. It looks like you should be passing down:

```
<MySelect handleChange={event => .. } />
```

The following notation is incorrect:

```
{() => {
  if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length >0) {
    this.props.items.map(this.renderSelectOption);
  }
}}
```

Firstly because this is a function declaration, and inside JSX you need components.

You could use a function here, as long as you called it right away.. but you would also need to return the array from calling `map`.

```
{() => {
  if (this.props.items && this.props.items.length > 0) {
    return this.props.items.map(this.renderSelectOption); // added return
  }
}()} <-- parens to invoke function (IIFE)
```

..but this could be more succinctly written without the function expression or the `if` statement like so:

```
{ this.props.items && // if exists
  this.props.items.length > 0 && // if has length
  this.props.items.map(this.renderSelectOption) // render array   
}
```

You could golf this further by adding a default before calling `map`:

```
{ (this.props.items || []).map(this.renderSelectOption) }
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41417/)**

Comment: I had to tape that code in, so names are not missmatching in my code, perhaps just typos when transering.

Comment: Does the rest of my answer fix your issue?

Comment: I don't think so, unless I am missing the point. I am not sure I understand the concern with the anonymous function, this is working. The core issue is how do I make options re-render dynamically in my select component in the most elegant and proper way?

Comment: But the code you wrote won't work, at least not the way you have written it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

So the below works for me:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class MySelectComponent extends Component {

 static propTypes = {
  key: React.PropTypes.string,
  isMultiSelect: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  initialOptions: React.PropTypes.array,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func,
  disabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
  placeHolder: React.PropTypes.string,
  value: React.PropTypes.string,
  label: React.PropTypes.string
 }
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {}

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
 }
 renderOptions() {
  let options = [];
  if (this.props.placeHolder) {
   options.push(<option label={this.props.placeHolder} value=""></option>); 
  }
  if (this.state.options) {
   this.state.options.map(option => {
    options.push(<option label={option.label} value={option.value}></option>); 
   });
  } else if (this.props.initialOptions) {
   this.props.initialOptions.map(option => {
    options.push(<option label={option.label} value={option.value}></option>); 
   });
  }
  return options;
 }
 handleChange(event) {
  if (typeof this.props.onChange === "function") {
   this.props.onChange(event);
  }
 }
 render() {
  return(
    <select type='select'
      multiple={this.props.isMultiSelect}
      disabled={this.props.disabled}
      value={this.props.value}
      label={this.props.value}
      initialOptions={this.props.initialOptions}
      placeHolder={this.props.placeHolder}
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
      >
      {this.renderOptions()}     
    </select>
   );   
 }
}
```